# Rows as columns with lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables that look like this:

Table *cars*

```
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+
| car_id | attribute | value |  brand  |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+
|      1 | colore    | rosso | Ferrari |
|      1 | prezzo    | 100   | Ferrari |
|      2 | couleur   | bleu  | Renault |
|      2 | prix      | 50    | Renault |
|      3 | colore    | blu   | Ferrari |
|      3 | prezzo    | 100   | Ferrari |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

Table *translations*

```
+--------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------+------------------+
| original_attribute | original_value |  brand  | translated_attribute | translated_value |
+--------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------+------------------+
| colore             | rosso          | Ferrari | color                | red              |
| prezzo             | 100            | Ferrari | price                | 100              |
| colore             | blu            | Ferrari | color                | blue             |
| couleur            | bleu           | Renault | color                | blue             |
| prix               | 50             | Renault | price                | 50               |
+--------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------+------------------+
```

I am trying to get to a table that looks like this:

```
+-------------------+-------+-------------+--------------------+
| translated_car_id | color | price       | translated_brand   |
+-------------------+-------+-------------+--------------------+
|                 1 | red   |         100 | Ferrari            |
|                 2 | blue  |          50 | Renault            |
|                 3 | blue  |         100 | Ferrari            |
+-------------------+-------+-------------+--------------------+
```

At the moment, I am using below code. It works, but is excruciatingly slow.

```sql
SELECT
    car_id translated_car_id,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN translations.translated_attribute = 'color' THEN translations.translated_value
    END) color,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN translations.translated_attribute = 'price' THEN translations.translated_value
    END) price,
    brand translated_brand
FROM
    cars c
        INNER JOIN
    translations ON (c.attribute = translations.original_attribute
        AND c.brand = translations.brand
        AND c.value = relations.original_value)
GROUP BY c.car_id
```

Anybody have an idea on how to make the query or the structure more efficient? Would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a language_id column - it will help you to filter translation by language without need to do MAX() and CASE() magic

Comment: Use language instead of brand for translations. So you don't need to duplicate the translations for Ferrari and Fiat.

Comment: Are there any indexes on the tables? When you run queries, are the queries limited or are they trying to get large sections of data like for reports or batch processing? Roughly how much data and how slow?

Comment: There is an index on car_id. I'm running the queries on large pieces of data with an eye on saving the result table separately for further processing. _cars_ currently has about 250k rows. _translations_ has 30k rows, and 10 columns (so 10 translated attributes). I'm not actually sure how slow it is as it times out even for low limits. Appending "WHERE car_id =1" gets evaluated in about 4 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find MySql doesn't have hash matches, which would be useful here. So I'm assuming that everything is being done as nested loop joins.

My concern is that because there isn't an index on translations, for every row in cars it has to scan the translations table to find the matching rows.

I would recommend a clustered index on translations(original_value, brand, original_attribute). (ms-sql does best with most specific first everything else being equal, not sure about MySql) That way it can go right to the row that it needs to match to. That should allow queries with one car to be done quickly.

If you can reduce the translations from manufacturer to language that would certainly help with the size of the translation table, but you would have to be sure that it works with your dataset because it does take away a level of flexibility.

I think that MySql will be able to use the index on cars to process the GROUP BY efficiently, but I will propose a more normalized schema where you don't need the group by.

```
car   
-------------
car_id
brand

car_attribute
------------
car_id
attribute
value
clustered_index(car_id, attribute)

brand_attribute
------------
brand_attribute_id
brand
attribute
translated_attribute
clustered_index(brand, translated_attribute)

brand_attribute_value
------------
brand_attribute_id
value
translated_value
clustered_index(brand_attribute_id, value)
```

And here's the query to do it that way.

```
SELECT
    car.car_id,
    color_brand_value.translated_value AS color,
    price_brand_value.translated_value AS price,
    car.brand
FROM
    car

    INNER JOIN brand_attribute AS color_brand
        ON color_brand.brand = car.brand
            AND color_brand.translated_attribute = 'color'
    INNER JOIN car_attribute AS color_attribute
        ON color_attribute.car_id = car.car_id
            AND color_attribute.attribute = brand.attribute
    INNER JOIN brand_attribute_value AS color_brand_value
        ON color_brand_value.brand_attribute_id = color_brand.brand_attribute_id
            AND color_brand_value.value = color_attribute.value

    INNER JOIN brand_attribute AS price_brand
        ON price_brand.brand = car.brand
            AND price_brand.translated_attribute = 'price'
    INNER JOIN car_attribute AS price_attribute
        ON price_attribute.car_id = car.car_id
            AND price_attribute.attribute = brand.attribute
    INNER JOIN brand_attribute_value AS price_brand_value
        ON price_brand_value.brand_attribute_id = price_brand.brand_attribute_id
            AND price_brand_value.value = price_attribute.value
```

It's definitely more complicated to do it this way. With your situation I'm not sure it's better, but something to consider if the first option isn't good enough.

My background is in mssql, so there may be differences that I'm not aware of. Please leave comments if I've missed or got something wrong.

Comment: Adding the clustered index helped by several orders of magnitude – thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help